# Terraform Relative path

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to update my Terraform to use a relative path for the state file.

My file structure is:

```
dev
   ecs_service
      lib
         ecs-task.json
      proxymodule
         main.tf
      provider.tf
      terragrunt.hcl
```

I want the update the backend to use a relative path. Right now it is:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket  = "software.terraform.auth"
    region  = "eu-west-1"
    key     = "retail-squad/validation/dev/ecs-service.tfstate"
  }
}
```

I want to make the key path relative. For example, if i moved it from a dev folder or uat the path would be "insurance-retail-squad-2/bank-details-validation/uat/ecs-service.tfstate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off using terraform workspaces and leaving the path the same. So you would create a workspace per environment.

Or you can use the init command to tell it  which state path to use:

```
terraform init \
    -backend-config="address=demo.consul.io" \
    -backend-config="path=example_app/terraform_state" \
    -backend-config="scheme=https"
```